# Below code is not working. data: form, is giving error

Tags: ajax, ajaxform

"data: form" is giving me

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

in console in chrome

```
let form=new FormData(this);            
$.ajax({
url:"RegisterServlet",
type:'POST'
data: form,`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier `
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){console.log(data)},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){console.log(jqXHR)},
processData: false,
contentType: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your Ajax API call with the below code and add an attribute in the form tag like id="formId" Maybe this will help you call your Ajax with form submission.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Before the below code, add an Ajax cdn link.

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#formId').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'post.php',
                    data: $('#formId').serialize(),
                    success: function() {
                        alert('form was submitted');
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
```